# Building an adjacency list graph using link list / vector

Tags: c++, adjacency-list

This is my first go at building a graph and i've decide to use a LL to connect my vectors (or nodes or elements, whatever they're called) and each one of my nodes has a vector that holds pointers to nodes. I've created a "**addEdge**" function in my graph class but it seems to be breaking my program. My addElement class seems to be working fine, as it will add and print them out perfectly. But when I try to add an edge, it breaks. I went through the debugger and it breaks at

`while(curr->next != NULL || curr->val != n)`

Any ideas why?

```
#include "element.h"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"
#include "functional"

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
public:
    element *head;

    Graph(int V)
    {
        head = NULL;
        vector <element*> nodes;
    }

    void addElement(int val)
    {
        if (head == NULL) 
        {
            element *newelement = new element(NULL, NULL, val);
            head = newelement;
            return ;
        }
        element *newelement = new element(NULL,NULL, val);
        element *curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = newelement;
        newelement->prev = curr;
        return;
    }
    void addEdge(int n, int edge)
    {
        element *e = head;
        element *curr = head;

        if(curr = NULL)
        {
            cout<<"There are no elements in your graph to connect";
            return;
        }
        while(e->next != NULL || e->val != edge)
        {
            cout<<"Looking";
            e = e->next;
        }
        if(e->val != edge)
        {
            cout<<"Your edge node doesn't exist";
            return;
        }
        while(curr->next != NULL || curr->val != n)
        {
            cout<<"Looking for main node";
            curr = curr->next;
        }    
        if(curr->val != n)
        {
            cout<<"Could not find the main node";
            return;
        }
        curr->edges.push_back(e);
        cout<<"Edge connected";
        return;
    }
```

**node class**

```
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"
#include "functional"

using namespace std;
class element {
public:
    element(element* n = NULL, element *p = NULL, int num = NULL)
    {
        val = num;
        next = n;
        prev = p;
    }
    int val;
    element *prev;
    element *next;
    vector<element*> edges;
};
```

Comment: #include "vector" should be #include <vector>, similar for iostream and functional header.

Comment: Oops. Still not the fix, though.

Comment: if(curr = NULL), this assignment is typo here ? or its also present in you code ? I guess you mean if( curr == NULL ) here